# "Class not Registered" restoring a Sharepoint ( WSS ) 2003 backup.dat file

Tags: sharepoint, backup, wss, restore

I need to do some work with a backup WSS .dat file and I'm having real trouble making it do anything.

I've got it installed through stsadm and that appears to have gone smoothly, but the site now redirects me to an error page - just the classic "File Not Found" one, but in the URL it suggests the errortext would be "Class not Registered" if there was a more informative error message.

When I run "stsadm -0 enumsites -url=http://my-restored-site/" I get this:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\60\BIN
\stsadm" -o enumsites -url http://my-restored-site

<Sites Count="1">
  <Site Url="http://my-restored-site" Error="Class not registered" />
</Sites>
```

Is there any way for me to tell what class is not registered or is there something else altogether going on here? I have enabled Sharepoint logging but it appears to have had absolutely no effect, certainly no file exists on the path I have asked it to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I do in such a case:

Use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to track down registry usage. Have an eye on `HKCR\CLSID` and `NAME NOT FOUND` results therein.

Take note of the CLSIDs it is not finding, Google them up to get a clue if they might have to do with your problem. Find out which .dll provides them, and register that .dll with regsvr32 (or use the respective installer for the missing component, if a whole bunch of stuff is missing).